# Roll back code to previous build or version in xcode

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I tried to get my app backwards compatible to ios 9. After autocompleting, I couldn't go back and undo the changes and now nothing works. I have the app on the appstore, is there a way to go back to that version, download a backup of it? I want my old code back from version 1.

Comment: You should use a VCS like git: https://git-scm.com/ Furthermore this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20206664/1567737

Comment: I know, I will from now on. It was my first app.

Comment: If you've deleted the source, it's over. You can't get the project back from the compiled application. Every programmer should use version control (Git is the most frequently used) *and* also do regular backups. Please do it from now on. :)